# How can i use Regex to get hebrew strings/words from html file?

Tags: c#, regex

In the top of Form1 i did:

```
private static readonly Regex AnyWordRegex = new Regex(@"((?<word>[a-zA-Z]{4,}))", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

In the constructor i did:

```
string file = File.ReadAllText(OriginalHtmlFilePath);
string strippedHtml = StripHtml(file);
```

OriginalHtmlFilePath in this case including html file with hebrew words.

This is the StripHtml :

```
public static string StripHtml(string htmlString)
        {
            return StripHtmlRegex.Replace(htmlString, @"|");
        }
```

After it i see that strippedHtml contain hebrew words.
Then im doing in the constructor:

```
_words = ExtractWords(strippedHtml);
```

_words is List

```
private static List<string> ExtractWords(string text)
        {
            MatchCollection matchCollection = AnyWordRegex.Matches(text);
            return (from Match match in matchCollection select match.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
        }
```

After doing the ExtractWords i see that the List _words contain only english words.
About 608 words only english. But the site im working on in this case is www.walla.co.il or www.ynet.co.il which is an hebrew sites.

If im working on cnn.com or foxnews.com any english sites everything is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\p{L}` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` to match all letters in all alphabets or `[\p{IsHebrew}a-zA-Z]` to be more specific.

Comment: Anirudh then how can i get all words from html file without regex ? I tried htmlagilitypack but didn't find something that will do it good so far.

Comment: @HaimKashi: You use Html Agility Pack to extract the text, and then use regular expressions to extract the words from the text.